# Execute Python code in new environment

Tags: python, objective-c, ios, pyobjc

Some time ago I've written an IDE for Python on iOS for my iPod Touch using PyObjC (ported to iOS by Saurik, installed via Cydia).
I use the 'exec' statement to evaluate the code that I entered in the Textfield.
But when subclassing an Objective-C class, i run into trouble when executing. The classes must not be declared two times, doing so raises a SystemError.
`SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call`

Is there a way to execute the code in a new environment while I'm still able to transfer some variables to it ?
Currently I execute it using  a copy of globals().

Thanks,
Niklas

Comment: Assuming it works on ios, you can put any objects into the globals/locals dicts which you pass to the exec statement.

Comment: This does unfortunately not work. As I already said i use a copy of globals() with the exec statement. It seems like subclasses are some kind of registered anywhere. Even This does not work: _class Foo(NSObject): pass \n del Foo_. Pressing Execute Button twice raises the same error.

Comment: i don't think you should be able to use `exec()` in iOS at all

Comment: Why do you think so ? Everything works well, except subclassing ObjC Classes. I read somewhere, that it is only possible to declare an ObjC class only once with a name per Python process, and this is exactly the problem. I'd need to create a new process of python that runs the code, but I don't know how.